# Login Service implementation in angularjs not working

Tags: html, angularjs, rest, post

This is my controller which is calling the login service

```
mod.controller("loginCtrl",function($scope,loginService,$http)
{
      $scope.Userlogin = function()
      {
          var User = {
              userid :$scope.uname,
              pass:$scope.pass
          };

          var res = UserloginService(User);

          console.log(res);
          alert("login_succ");
      }          
});
```

And  this is the login service code which takes the User variable and checks for username & password

```
mod.service("loginService",function($http,$q) {
    UserloginService = function(User) {

    var deffered = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method:'POST',
        url:'http://localhost:8080/WebApplication4_1/login.htm',
        data:User
    }).then(function(data) {
        deffered.resolve(data);
    }).error(function(status) {
        deffered.reject({
            status:status
        });
    });
    return deffered.promise;

    // var response = $http({
    //
    //   method:"post",
    //   url:"http://localhost:8080/WebApplication4_1/login.htm",
    //   data:JSON.stringify(User),
    //   dataType:"json"
    // });

    //  return "Name";
  }
});
```

I have created a rest api using springs which upon passing json return back the username and password in json like this

[image: Postman screenshot]

Console shows me this error for angular
[image: Error in console]

Comment: *"not working"* is a virtually meaningless problem statement that tells us next to nothing

Comment: Did you provide headers for that?

Comment: Enable CORS in your rest API

Comment: hmm .. will try enabling cors for rest

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable CORS  for your application for guidance see this link
https://htet101.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/cors-with-angularjs-and-spring-rest/

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use Factory to do what you're trying to do, which would be something like this:

```
MyApp.factory('MyService', ["$http", function($http) {

  var urlBase = "http://localhost:3000";

  return {
    getRecent: function(numberOfItems) {
      return $http.get(urlBase+"/things/recent?limit="+numberOfItems);
    },
    getSomethingElse: function(url) {
      return $http.get(urlBase+"/other/things")
    },
    search: function (searchTerms) {
      return $http.get(urlBase+"/search?q="+searchTerms);
    }
  }

}]);
```

And then in your controller you can import `MyService` and then use it in this way:

```
MyService.getRecent(10).then(function(res) {
  $scope.things = res.data;
});
```

This is a great way to handle it, because you're putting the `.then` in your controller and you are able to control the state of the UI during a loading state if you'd like, like this:

```
// initialize the loading var, set to false
$scope.loading = false;

// create a reuseable update function, and inside use a promise for the ajax call,
// which is running inside the `Factory`
$scope.updateList = function() {
  $scope.loading = true;
  MyService.getRecent(10).then(function(res) {
    $scope.loading = false;
    $scope.things = res.data;
  });
};
$scope.updateList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The error in the console shows two issues with your code:

1. [**CORS**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) is not enabled in your api. To fix this you need to enable CORS using `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to your rest api.
2. `Unhandled rejection` error, as the way you are handling errors with '.error()' method is deprecated. 
   'Promise.error()' method is deprecated according to [**this**](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/1200) and this [**commit**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/a8f7e9cfde82ed7eaba3a868d8acafdf57f2d76f) in Angular js github repo. 
   Hence you need to change the way you are handling errors as shown below :

   ```
   $http().then(successCallback, errorCallback);

   function successCallback (res) {
       return res;
   }

   function errorCallback (err) {
       return err;
   }
   ```

One more thing in your code which can be avoided is you have defined a new promise and resolving it using `$q` methods, which is not required. `$http` itself returns a `promise` by default, which you need not define again inside it to use it as a Promise. You can directly use `$http.then()`.